# how to Block a method until another method executes in c# .net

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-synchronization

I have an application, in which I'm sending a command to hardware controller, then controller responds back to that command. In this, I have a queue of commands and I send them one by one, now i want to send all commands synchronously, means when I receive first commands response then only I will send next command.
I have two methods, one for send commands and another for handling received commands.

Answer (score 6):

This is called signaling and the simplest way to implement it is via `ManualResetEvent`.

if you call `WaitOne` on a `ManualResetEvent` object, the current thread gets blocked until another thread "signals" it to continue by calling `Set` on the same object:

```
var signal = new ManualResetEvent(false); // instantiate in "unsignaled" state

new Thread (() =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Sending command to hardware controller...");

    // send your command
    // ...

    Console.WriteLine("Done.");
    signal.Set(); // signal the waiting thread that it can continue.
}).Start();

Console.WriteLine("Waiting for hardware thread to do it's work...");
signal.WaitOne(); // block thread until we are signaled.
signal.Dispose();
Console.WriteLine("Got our signal! we can continue.");
```